# Why is variable automatically being passed by reference?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to call a function in the ROOT plotting package that accepts three variables. The relevant section in my code is:

```
int xwidth=0,ywidth=0;
Bool_t useangle=0;
vIt->GetBoundingBox(xwidth,ywidth,useangle);
```

where vIt is an iterator to an object with GetBoundingBox as a class member function. (Bool_t is just a typedef that ROOT uses).

Now, when I compile, I get the following error from g++:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘TText::GetBoundingBox(int&, int&, Bool_t&)’
/home/bwhelan/Programs/MODIFIED//External/root/5.30.00/include/root/TText.h:57: note:   candidates are: virtual void TText::GetBoundingBox(UInt_t&, UInt_t&, Bool_t)
```

My question is why is useangle being passed by reference here, instead of by value? I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: Why do you try to pass signed integers to unsigned parameters?

Comment: The variable is passed by reference because that is what the method takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that the bool is passed by reference but that you line

```
int xwidth=0,ywidth=0;
```

Should be of type `UInt_t`

```
UInt_t xwidth=0u,ywidth=0u;
```

The compiler doesn't know how you want to pass the variable to function with the unkown overload so it just assumes you meant by ref.

Comment: Thanks for that - ROOT uses a lot of typedefs that I generally ignore (e.g Int_t instead of int) and in my confusion I had missed that it wanted an unsigned int.

Comment: @Wheels2050 it can be painful at times but it is good not to ignore typedef and namespace prefixes.

Comment: I realise it's good practice to use the correct typedefs etc., but as I'm usually writing programs for data analysis in my research they often only get used once - as a result, I tend to take shortcuts to write things quickly, and have gotten into the habit of doing that everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

In C++, upon overload resolution, a set of viable overloads is selected, and the one candidate that requires the least
conversions (does it require changing the constness? is a promotion of integer to floating point needed?)
is chosen. If there are multiple matches that have the same weight, you have an ambiguous call and get an error
(e.g.: `int foo(int &x, int y); int foo(int x, int &y); ... int a,b; foo(a,b);` is ambiguous).

However, in your case, no valid conversion sequence can be found, because there exists no valid conversion from 
`int&` to `unsigned int&` (sidenote: there exists a conversion from `int` to `unsigned int` and vice versa), because
references to unrelated types are not compatible at all.

About the error message: The compiler uses the weakest allowed binding to filter out the set of viable functions. For `int`, this is `int&`. 
But because no viable set of functions is found, an error message is spit out. The author of the message did not base
it on your code, but rather on the data he/she has had for the search, which is `int&`. However, he/she
correctly proposes a viable alternative that really exists.

So we have more a compiler diagnostic *quality* issue here, rather than a C++ *correctness* issue.

---

From the standard, here's the table of conversion. The least are required to make a function call
valid, the better the match:

```
Conversion                         
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
No conversions required            | Identity
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion        | Lvalue transformation
Array-to-pointer conversion        |
Function-to-pointer conversion     |
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
Qualification conversions          | Qualification adjustment
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
Integral promotions                | Promotion
Floating point promotion           |
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
Integral conversions               | Conversion
Floating point conversions         |
Floating-integral conversions      |
Pointer conversions                |
Pointer to member conversions      |
Boolean conversions                |
-----------------------------------+----------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the function is declared to take xwidth and ywidth as `UInt_t&`, but xwidth and ywidth are `int`s, which cannot be converted to `UInt_t&`.

Comment: +1 It is very important to learn to read error messages and know what they mean. The compiler is trying to describe what you have at the place of call, and the different candidates that it has considered.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the function have the following arguments

```
UInt_t&, UInt_t&, Bool_t
```

and you are passing

```
int&, int&, Bool_t&
```

Either convert your `int` to `UInt_t` before you call the method or directly declare them as `UInt_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

Compiler messages are more or less useful. As it is, since it did not find a method that it can call with the arguments you supplied, the compiler is trying to synthetize, from the arguments you gave, a method signature that could have worked.

This is, unfortunately, ultimately doomed to fail, as there are just so many possible variations, but then gcc's messages have never been too great.

Clang took another approach, which I happen to prefer. Instead of trying to imagine what the function you wanted to call looks like and then listing the candidates and leaving you to spot the differences, it tells you why each candidate was discarded.

```
void func(unsigned&, unsigned&);

int something() {
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  func(a, b);
  return a + b;
}
```

Yields the following error message:

```
/tmp/webcompile/_3246_0.cc:5:3: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
  func(a, b);
  ^~~~
/tmp/webcompile/_3246_0.cc:1:6: note: candidate function not viable:
    no known conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned int &' for 1st argument; 
void func(unsigned&, unsigned&);
```

Which I find much more useful. Patching this by turning `a` into an `unsigned` and leaving `b` as is we get:

```
/tmp/webcompile/_3710_0.cc:1:6: note: candidate function not viable:
    no known conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned int &' for 2nd argument; 
void func(unsigned&, unsigned&);
```

And this way we advance one argument at a time until we "fixed" the call to our liking.

Comment: +1: Lattner did indeed a great job focusing on good error message from the beginning on. As for your post: I think `synthesize` does not hit the point correctly. Synthesization is something that only happens for templates regarding the standard, and we don't have synthesization of function signatures here. However, we have a possible synthesization of valid conversion sequences.

Comment: @phresnel: Lattner did not do much on Clang, his work is focused on LLVM. The Clang team is lead by Ted Kremenek as far as I know, and the part about diagnostic would fall into Douglas Gregor's lap I believe, as he is responsible for the semantic analysis part. Still, good diagnostics are a goal established and a focus of the whole team. As for the synthetization: this is what gcc does when forging the diagnostic message, it's unused for the actual overload resolution, but it's what you get in the message, which makes it confusing.

Comment: My error, of course I meant llvm; afair one of his (quite interesting) research papers mentioned good error messages to be a design goal. I have btw myself made the experience of stuffing good error messages into an already existing LISP-like-language compiler; it was a mess, and LISP is not known for implying complex compilers :) I am currently rewriting it, with diagnostics being an integral part at any stage of compilation, even the later stages still carry some code-positional information (from tokenization to full symbol resolution). But I am spamming your comments-section, sorry.

Comment: @phresnel: no problem, good diagnostics in compiler are certainly of interest to me :) One of the issues I have with GCC is that part of the diagnostics ("unused") are susceptible to the optimization level... knowing that we usually develop in Debug mode, it's quite annoying to discover a new warning when preparing to ship code for the test stage :x